# Get localized month name using native JS

Tags: javascript, date, localization

It's possible to do this to get the localized full month name using native [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript).

```
var objDate = new Date("10/11/2009"),
    locale = "en-us",
    month = objDate.toLocaleString(locale, { month: "long" });
```

But this only gets the month number for a given date. I'd simply like to get the month name corresponding to a month number. For example, if I do `getMonth(2)` it would return `February`. How can I implement `getMonth` using native [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)(no libraries like `moment`)?

Comment: It's a 1-line-solution: `new Date(2020, monthIndex, 1).toLocaleString("en-us", {month: "long"});`

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You are already close:

```js
var getMonth = function(idx) {

  var objDate = new Date();
  objDate.setDate(1);
  objDate.setMonth(idx-1);

  var locale = "en-us",
      month = objDate.toLocaleString(locale, { month: "long" });

    return month;
}

console.log(getMonth(1));
console.log(getMonth(12));
```

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to do it without needing to instantiate a date object?

Comment: I wouldn't rely on the language at all: just add an array of month names in your localisation file (or make it if you don't have one).

Comment: I realize that this is a very old answer, but this is one of those cases where it doesn't work properly for February on the 29th, 30th or 31st of another month because the `Date` object is initialized with the current date. This can be solved by adding `objDate.setDate(1);` before setting the month.

Answer (score 2):

To get all the months of a year and days of the week, loop over a set of dates and use *toLocaleString* with appropriate options to get the required values:

```js
function getLocalDayNames() {
  let d = new Date(2000,0,3); // Monday
  let days = [];
  for (let i=0; i<7; i++) {
    days.push(d.toLocaleString('default',{weekday:'long'}));
    d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
  }
  return days;
}

console.log(getLocalDayNames());

function getLocalMonthNames() {
  let d = new Date(2000,0); // January
  let months = [];
  for (let i=0; i<12; i++) {
    months.push(d.toLocaleString('default',{month:'long'}));
    d.setMonth(i + 1);
  }
  return months;
}

console.log(getLocalMonthNames());
```

The language *default* means *toLocaleString* uses the default language of the implementation that the code is running in.

Answer (score 2):

You can use localization formatting:

```
const DAYS_IN_WEEK = 7;
const MONTHS_IN_YEAR = 12;

function localizedWeekdayNames(
  locale: Intl.LocalesArgument = "default",
  dateStyle: Intl.RelativeTimeFormatStyle = "short"
): string[] {
  const dayNames: string[] = [];
  const currentDate = new Date();
  while (currentDate.getDay() !== 0) {
    currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
  }
  for (let day = 0; day < DAYS_IN_WEEK; day++) {
    dayNames.push(
      currentDate.toLocaleDateString(locale, { weekday: dateStyle })
    );
    currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
  }
  return dayNames;
}

function localizedMonthNames(
  locale: Intl.LocalesArgument = "default",
  dateStyle: Intl.RelativeTimeFormatStyle = "short"
): string[] {
  const monthNames: string[] = [];
  const currentDate = new Date();
  while (currentDate.getMonth() !== 0) {
    currentDate.setMonth(currentDate.getMonth() + 1);
  }
  for (let month = 0; month < MONTHS_IN_YEAR; month++) {
    monthNames.push(
      currentDate.toLocaleDateString(locale, { month: dateStyle })
    );
    currentDate.setMonth(currentDate.getMonth() + 1);
  }
  return monthNames;
}

// ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"] 
console.log(localizedWeekdayNames());

// ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"] 
console.log(localizedMonthNames());
```

Here is the generated JS with some additional localization output.

```js
const DAYS_IN_WEEK = 7;
const MONTHS_IN_YEAR = 12;

function localizedWeekdayNames(locale = "default", dateStyle = "short") {
  const dayNames = [];
  const currentDate = new Date();
  while (currentDate.getDay() !== 0) {
    currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
  }
  for (let day = 0; day < DAYS_IN_WEEK; day++) {
    dayNames.push(currentDate.toLocaleDateString(locale, {
      weekday: dateStyle
    }));
    currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
  }
  return dayNames;
}

function localizedMonthNames(locale = "default", dateStyle = "short") {
  const monthNames = [];
  const currentDate = new Date();
  while (currentDate.getMonth() !== 0) {
    currentDate.setMonth(currentDate.getMonth() + 1);
  }
  for (let month = 0; month < MONTHS_IN_YEAR; month++) {
    monthNames.push(currentDate.toLocaleDateString(locale, {
      month: dateStyle
    }));
    currentDate.setMonth(currentDate.getMonth() + 1);
  }
  return monthNames;
}

// Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat
console.log(...localizedWeekdayNames());

// Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
console.log(...localizedMonthNames());

// domingo lunes martes miércoles jueves viernes sábado
console.log(...localizedWeekdayNames('es-ES', 'long'));

// enero febrero marzo abril mayo junio
// julio agosto septiembre octubre noviembre diciembre
console.log(...localizedMonthNames('es-ES', 'long'));
```